# Node server web app don't want to run on mobile device with mobile data, It's hosted to VPS

Tags: node.js, mobile, server

I have a problem with my Vue.js website.It's a vue with node express frontend, and another node express on a different port as backend.
It works fine on a desktop, also on a mobile device, but on mobile when I turn off the wifi and try to reload the website with the mobile data, it does not load.Even stranger is the fact that I tried on many mobile devices, and 1/3 of them has no this problem (and the devices are different, iphone, android, with chrome, with safary)
And last, during this phenomenon, when I try to access the rest apis of the backend, everything works fine there. All the backend and the frontend are hosted on a VPS server.

My web app
https://conndesk.com/

The response headers that I am using.

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
```

My config file for connection with the back-end

```
{
    "ip": "46.101.12.218",
    "api": "https://conndesk.com:444",
    "files": "https://conndesk.com:444",
    "domainName": "conndesk.com"
}
```

New update !!!  I tried this and it does the same, with wifi works but at mobile data don't. There is no vue.js or express.js. When I change the ports to something different from the default ones, works nice at both mobile data and wifi. It looks like it's a server problem , not Vue js

```
const https = require("https"),
    http = require("http"),
    { readFileSync } = require("fs"),
    sslPort = 443,
    port = 80;

var https_server = (req, res, next) => {
    return res.end("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
};

var http_server = (req, res, next) => {
    return res.end("bbbbbbbbbbbbb");
};

/** HTTPS */
https
    .createServer(
        {
            key: readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem", "utf8"),
            cert: readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/fullchain.pem", "utf8"),
        },
        https_server
    )
    .listen(sslPort, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running at port ${sslPort}...`);
    });

/** HTTP */
http.createServer(http_server).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at port ${port}...`);
});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the first obvious guess must be that the frontend calls the backend on a local network address (i.e. 192.168.1.123) which obviously wont work when you turn off wifi, and on the devices that it does still work, you've simply missed to clear cache.

Comment: My second guess would be CORS, which you are handling seemingly correctly, but on which route?
Are you using `app.options('/some-route')` or `app.all('/some-route')` to handle the preflight? 
Because you are not showing that part of your code, we have to question that first. 

Do you have any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: It's not possible this one, the project is hosted at digitalocean, I developed it there and never been local. I created also a small config file in the public directory, to be able to move or change the back-end without building it again ""I added the config code in the question"". Thank you ippi.